# use function in every two columns in R

Tags: r, apply

Now I have a data set that looks like this:

```
> data
             a       b        c         d
[1,] 0.5943590 2.195610 0.5332164 1.3004142
[2,] 0.7635876 1.917823 0.9714945 1.3251010
[3,] 0.9942722 2.350122 1.2048159 1.1675700
[4,] 0.3736785 1.876318 0.9109197 0.8520509
```

And then I want to use a function for every two columns, for example,

```
F2<- function(x,y) (sum((x - y) ^ 2)) #define function
F2(data$a, data$b) #use function for first two columns
F2(data$a, data$c) #use function for first and third columns
F2(data$b, data$c) #use function for second and third columns
..................
```

How to use apply family to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

That's a job for `combn`:

```
#some data
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(16),4)

F2<- function(x,y) (sum((x - y) ^ 2))

res <- matrix(NA, ncol(m), ncol(m))

res[lower.tri(res)] <- combn(ncol(m), 2, 
                             FUN=function(ind) F2(m[,ind[1]], m[,ind[2]]))

print(res)

#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3] [,4]
# [1,]       NA       NA       NA   NA
# [2,] 2.992875       NA       NA   NA
# [3,] 4.293073 8.320698       NA   NA
# [4,] 7.944818 6.484424 16.44946   NA

#for nicer printing
as.dist(res)

#           1         2         3
# 2  2.992875                    
# 3  4.293073  8.320698          
# 4  7.944818  6.484424 16.449463
```

And of course for this specific function you should better use `dist`, which is optimized for that kind of distance calculations:

```
dist(t(m))^2

#           1         2         3
# 2  2.992875                    
# 3  4.293073  8.320698          
# 4  7.944818  6.484424 16.449463
```